# Show all WordPress authors then filter the list by meta key

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to show a list of all my WordPress site authors on the front end of the site.  I want users of the site to be able to select a region from a drop down menu and the list of users to be filtered by the selected region.  The region is set up as a Meta Key called 'county'.

I have followed the example in [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23282/how-to-search-for-users-based-on-added-user-metadata) which has helped for the most part, but the issue that I am currently having is the list of users is empty and only populates when a search is ran.

The code I currently have set up is as follows:

```
add_shortcode('user_search','My_User_search');
function My_User_search($atts = null){
    $out = user_search_form();
    if (isset($_GET['user_search']) && $_GET['user_search'] == "search_users" && isset($_GET['search_by'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $metakey = $_GET['search_by'];
        $args = array(
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'  => 'AND',
            array( 
                'key'     => $metakey,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'rescue_pound_vet',
                'value'   => 'rescue'
            )
        )
    );

         if (isset($_GET['s_value'])){
            $metavalue = $_GET['s_value'];
            $args['meta_value'] = $metavalue;
         } 

        $search_users = get_users($args);

        $out .= '<div class="user_search_results">';
        if (count($search_users) >0){

            // here we loop over the users found and return whatever you want eg:
            $out .= '<ul>';
            foreach ($search_users as $user) {
                $out .= '<li>' . $user->user_nicename . '</li>';
                $out .= '<li>' . $user->county . '</li>';
            }
            $out .= '</ul>';
        }else{
            $out .= 'No users found, try searching for something else.';
        }
        $out .= '</div>';
    }
    return $out;
}

//function to display user search form
function user_search_form(){
    $metavalue = $metakey = '';
    if (isset($_GET['search_by'])){
        $metakey = $_GET['search_by'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['s_value'])){
        $metavalue = $_GET['s_value'];
    }
    $re = '<div class="user_search"><form action="" name="user_s" method="get">
        <label for="search_by">Search by:</label>
            <select id="search_by" name="search_by">';
    if ($metakey != ''){
        $re.= '"';
        $re.= ($metakey == "county") ? '<option value="county" selected="selected">County</option>': '<option value="county">County</option>';
    }else{
        $re .= '
            <option value="county">County</option>';
    }
    $re .= '
            </select>
        <label for="s_value">Value:</label>
            <input id="s_value" name="s_value" type="text" value="'.$metavalue.'"/>
            <input name="user_search" id="user_search" type="hidden" value="search_users"/>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form></div>';
    return $re;
}
```

Is there a way to set up the $args to show all authors first, then amend as a user to the site carries out a search.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The initial set of arguments are in an if statement that only runs if the search is carried out.  I amended this so a basic set of arguments ran first and then if the search was used, only then would the arguments with the variable run.

This is the part that was amended and fixed:

```
add_shortcode('user_search','My_User_search');
function My_User_search($atts = null){
    $out = user_search_form();

    $args = array(
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'rescue_pound_vet',
                'value'   => 'rescue'
            )
        )
    );

    if (isset($_GET['user_search']) && $_GET['user_search'] == "search_users" && isset($_GET['search_by'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $metakey = $_GET['search_by'];
        $args = array(
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'  => 'AND',
            array( 
                'key'     => $metakey,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'rescue_pound_vet',
                'value'   => 'rescue'
            )
        )
    );
}
```